# Vuex store authentication and axios interceptor returns undefinied

Tags: vue.js, axios, frontend, vuex

Scratching my head on this issue. I do all the authentication logic in my vuex store. When using an axios interceptor to catch the error, it always returns undefined. When I only perform the interceptor on other calls, it works fine. (did this by adding if(token) { api.interceptor...}

My code is as follow

store/index.js

```
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('auth_request')
        api({url: '/api/auth/login', data: user, method: 'POST' })
        .then((resp) => {
          let token = resp.data.token
          //let sites = JSON.stringify(resp.data.sites)
          let user = JSON.stringify(resp.data.user)
          localStorage.setItem('token', token)
          api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
          commit('auth_success', token)
          //commit('set_sites', sites)
          commit('set_default', resp.data.user.default_site)
          commit('set_user', user)
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          commit('auth_error', err)
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    },
```

axios.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from 'src/store'

let token = localStorage.getItem('token')

const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' })

api.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  console.log('ok')
  return response;
}, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    store.dispatch('log_out')
  }
  return error
});
```

Login.vue

````
          this.loading = true
          this.$store.dispatch('login', this.user)
          .then(() => {
            this.loading = false
            this.$router.push('/')
             
          })
          .catch(error => {
               this.loading = false
                this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message
          })
      },```


Dont be hard on me, junior in this ;-)
````

Comment: Are you *sure* it's returning a 401 and not a `Network Error`? Common that backends aren't configured correctly all the time. If it's a network error, axios will never receive a `401` and you'll need to solve for that problem first.

Comment: Post calls start at my side with an options request. 204, depending on the error i throw a 401 or 422.